# I cannot use OpenFile code in flutter project

Tags: flutter, pdf

I try to download my users details in pdf, so I use [ OpenFile.open('$path/$fileName'); ] to open the pdf, so I import OpenFile package. when I run the project, it shows me this error:

[image]

please help in this

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- check if the package `open_file` supports null safety (it's indicated by a small icon beside the package name on their page), and then update the version of the package in your `pubspec.yaml`, or totally remove the version constraints, like this:

  ```
  dependencies:
     #other packages here...
     open_file: #here you probably have some numeric values, like ^2.0.0, remove them
  ```
- set the flutter version used by your app to a version without null safety: you have to change these lines in your `pubspec.yaml` and set the starting version to some values below 2.12.0

  ```
   environment:
      sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
  ```